# Ordinal variables relation analysis

Tags: ordinal-data

I have a data set containing 10 subjects and students' grades in those subjects (e.g., A+, A, B+, B, C+, C, D+, D). I want to find out out if the grades in one subject are affecting the grades for other subjects. Should I go with regression analysis? If yes, then should I replace grades with some numbers before doing the regression?

```
A+   A+   B+   A    A    A+   A+   A+  A+  A+
```

Above is 1 row of the data set. This row signifies grades of a particular student in 10 different subjects in the exam. I want to know if grade in any subject influences the grade of another.

Comment: What exactly would it mean for "the grades of one subject [to affect] the grades for other subjects"? I don't know how you could figure this out because I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I need to know if one subject grade has an impact over another subject grade. For instance grade of subject 1 has some impact or relation with grade in subject 6. This data is just a single student performance in 10 subject. I have 60000 students similar grades in those 10 subjects. So I would like to analyse to find soms insights.. Thanx

Comment: As you say you have ordinal data so why you are asking about regression?

Comment: See advice against cross-posting in http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

"influences" sounds like some sort of causation. You cannot determine that from these data.

If you mean "are grades related to each other" then you might want cluster analysis.

If you want to look at each pair of subjects separately, you could run rank correlations among all pairs.

Comment: I would like to know if grade in one subject affects or have any relation with grades of other. This data is just 1 students grade in 10 subjects.. So my question is if grade in subject one has any influence over grade in subject 6 for instance. I have 60000 students data and their respective score in 10 subjects .  So if I can relate grades of students in different subjects to find some insights.